# android webview unfortunately has stopped on tablets

Tags: android, webview, tablet

I created android application via Android studio and published on google play, but in first version the application was not working with android v4.0.3, after searching i edited the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

And it is success, But now I get new error on tablets only 7 inch and 10 inch... 
when i request webview with external page, i get message (unfortunately has stopped) and quit from the app.

On the emulators it is works fine, the problem appears on devices only.

Note: android version on 7 inch is 4.2.2, and the version on 10 inch is 5.0.2.

what is the problem or what i should to do?

Comment: What message do you see in the logcat?

Comment: 05-11 08:23:31.963    1531-1536/***.***.**** I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-11 08:23:31.984    1531-1536/***.***.**** I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

** note: the emulators it is works fine, the problem appears on devices only.